# What is the benefit of hosting WCF service in WAS?

Tags: wcf

If we Host WCF in WAS then we do not need to install IIS completely. Is this really a big advantage of hosting in WAS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One benefit is that you could use binary bindings such as `netTcpBinding`.